# How to 'filter' a district by clicking on it in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, filter

I have created a basic layer of districts on a background google streetmap on QGIS. Using the qgis2leaflet plug in, I'm able to render a webpage of the same. I want the web product to be such that when a user clicks on a particular district (layer), it gets highlighted (to show that it is the district that has been 'selected') , zoomed in and displays the relevant information from the atribute table. How do I enable this filtering+zooming capability? (P.S: I read that the 'map events' funtionality in leaflet is the way to do it....but where exactly do I define these map events from QGIS desktop?)
Sorry if my question is stupid ......I'm new to geomapping softwares

Comment: It might be easier to do it directly in Leaflet?

Comment: @John Barca- Probably yes, just that I have never used javascript before so it might take more time than I have to get my POC ready.....Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Fair enough. Map events are quite easy in Leaflet, but I appreciate that Javascript can seem daunting when first approached -- though well worth the effort for what it opens up. I know nothing about qgis2leaflet, sorry.